# Realtime Display Value Change form Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am new to android studio and currently watching tutorials. As of now I have a Shopping cart activity where I can increment, decrement and delete items in cart. The thing is whenever I delete, add or deduct an item, the cart values does not update. I still need to change activities to see the changes. Also the item that I deleted still appears at the bottom of recyclerview items after the dialog appearance unless I change the activity and go back. Please help me how to apply real time update. Below are my class files for the cart activity and adapter class.

**CartActivity.java**

```java
        @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        if (EventBus.getDefault().hasSubscriberForEvent(MyUpdateCartEvent.class))
            EventBus.getDefault().removeStickyEvent(MyUpdateCartEvent.class);
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN_ORDERED, sticky = true)
    public void onUpdateCart(MyUpdateCartEvent event) {
        loadCartFromFirebase();
    }

private void loadCartFromFirebase() {
        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        if(fAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
            userId = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        } else {
            userId = "UNIQUE_USER_ID";
        }
        List<CartModel> cartModels = new ArrayList<>();
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference("cart")
                .child(userId)
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.exists()) {
                            for (DataSnapshot cartSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                                CartModel cartModel = cartSnapshot.getValue(CartModel.class);
                                cartModel.setKey(cartSnapshot.getKey());
                                cartModels.add(cartModel);
                            }
                            cartLoadListener.onCartLoadSuccess(cartModels);
                        } else {
                            cartLoadListener.onCartLoadFailed("Cart Empty");
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                        cartLoadListener.onCartLoadFailed(error.getMessage());
                    }
                });
    }

    private void init() {
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        cartLoadListener = this;
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recycler_cart.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        purchScrnBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> startActivity(new Intent(this, PurchaseActivity.class)));

    }

    @Override
    public void onCartLoadSuccess(List<CartModel> cartModelList) {
        double sum = 0;
        for (CartModel cartModel : cartModelList) {
            sum += cartModel.getTotalPrice();
        }
        textTotal.setText(new StringBuilder("$").append(sum));
        MyCartAdapter adapter = new MyCartAdapter(this, cartModelList);
        recycler_cart.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

**MyCartAdapter.java**

```java
package com.example.cart.adapter;

public class CartActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CartLoadListener {


    public MyCartViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new MyCartViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context)
                .inflate(R.layout.layout_cart_item, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyCartViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.minus.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            minusCartItem(holder,cartModelList.get(position));
        });
        
        holder.delete.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                    .setTitle("Delete item")
                    .setMessage("Do you really want to delete item")
                    .setNegativeButton("CANCEL", (dialogInterface, i) -> dialogInterface.dismiss())
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", (dialogInterface2, i) -> {

                        //Temp remove
                        notifyItemRemoved(position);
                        deleteFromFirebase(cartModelList.get(position));
                        dialogInterface2.dismiss();
                    }).create();
            dialog.show();
        });

    }

    private void deleteFromFirebase(CartModel cartModel) {
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference("cart")
                .child(userId)
                .child(cartModel.getKey())
                .removeValue()
                .addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(new MyUpdateCartEvent()));
    }

    @SuppressLint("SuspiciousIndentation")
    private void minusCartItem(MyCartViewHolder holder, CartModel cartModel) {
        if(cartModel.getQuantity() > 1)
            cartModel.setQuantity(cartModel.getQuantity()-1);
            cartModel.setTotalPrice(cartModel.getQuantity()*Float.parseFloat(cartModel.getPrice()));

            //update quantity
            holder.txtQuantity.setText(new StringBuilder().append(cartModel.getQuantity()));
            updateFirebase(cartModel);
    }

    public class MyCartViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        Unbinder unbinder;

        public MyCartViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted more than **300** (three hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.  Please take a moment and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hi @Alex this is noted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The thing is whenever I delete, add or deduct an item, the cart values does not update.

That's because you load data from Firebase with `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`, which only loads the data when you call it. If you want to continue to monitor the data for changes, use `addValueEventListener` instead.

Comment: Hi @Frank, Thanks for the solution this did work for deleting an item. May I know how can the same result also be achieved for adding and deducting an item?

Comment: Hi F@Frank, I'm not sure if adding ```@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }```

solved the issue but when I tried it, it worked.